# Insertar imagen en un objeto AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Estoy intentando insertar una imagen al atributo `pendingConfirmation` como lo pueden ver a continuación y me sale error de `sintax`

```
 $scope.colors = {
        status: {
            interested: "",
            pendingConfirmation: "{ background : 'default-grey-500' ,  border : 'default-grey-500' , color : 'default-grey-50' },{ images/negado.png }",
        }
    };
```

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 95 of the expression [{ background : 'default-grey-500' ,  border : 'default-grey-500' , color : 'default-grey-50' },{ images/negado.png }] starting at [,{ images/negado.png }]

Comment: como tienes formado el HTML? es valido lo que dices solo tienes que inyectarlo en un div

Comment: No se si no entendí bien tu pregunta, pero tu mismo te diste la solución, así como copiaste el ejemplo así la agregas con una ruta existente desde la cual puedas llamar la imagen, o entendí mal lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 106 of the expression [{ background : 'default-grey-500' ,  border : 'default-grey-500' , color : 'default-grey-50' , background-image : 'images/check.png' }] starting at [-image : 'images/check.png' }]. Este es el error que me sale es por ello que me di la oportunidad de preguntar.

Comment: quieres cambiar el estilo de una clase?

Comment: EL te esta diciendo que el guión que tienes en `background-image` no es permitido, entonces guárdalo como `backgroundImage`

Comment: Me pueden colaborar con el error que agregue en mi publicación editada. Gracias!!!

Comment: El último objeto es el problema (images/negado.png). Supongo ese es el valor, agregale comilla simple y ponle una clave.

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar al final este error? ¿Probaste a ponerle comillas al string de la imagen? Sería bueno que si diste con la solución la publicaras como respuesta. Gracias :)